# How to find the most frequent vowel and consonants in the text in C

Tags: c

For example the user entered this text : How arrree yooou

output ==> the most frequent vowel is : o
           the most frequent consonants is : r

Not : Here 'e' also a duplicate, but the most frequent one is 'o', I am looking for the most frequent

```
/* Initializes frequency of all characters to 0 */
for(i=0; i<MAX_CHARS; i++)
{
    freq[i] = 0;
}
/* Finds frequency of each characters */
i=0;
while(str[i] != '\0')
{
    ascii = ((int)str[i]=='a' || str[i]=='e' || str[i]=='i' ||
       str[i]=='o' || str[i]=='u' || str[i]=='A' ||
       str[i]=='E' || str[i]=='I' || str[i]=='O' ||
       str[i]=='U');

    vowels++;

    freq[ascii] += 1;

    i++;
}

/* Finds maximum frequency */
max = 0;
for(i=0; i<MAX_CHARS; i++)
{
    if(freq[i] > freq[max])
        max = i;
}


printf("Maximum occurring character is '%c' = %d times.", max, freq[max]);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Create an array, `int count[26] = {0}`.  When a letter is encountered, increment the appropriate index.

Comment: I don't have the time to put together an example for you but it might benefit you to know that strings in C are just char arrays. Also, consider the usefulness of case statements and regular expressions.

Comment: I create this `for(i=0; i<MAX_CHARS; i++)` and it works but the output is the most repeated letter not the most frequent vowel or consonants @FiddlingBits

Comment: Do not iterate over 0 to MAX_CHARS.  Instead, read a character from the stream until the stream is exhausted.

Comment: @Josiah I created the entire program, but it works according to the most repeated character without specifying whether it is vowel or consonants ,

Comment: @WilliamPursell I added the code. Can you specify what should I add?
The code works, but without specifying whether it is vowel or consonants

Comment: Your `ascii = ` is wrong: this is really computing 'is vowel', which is OK but isn't the place you need to test that, and that's not what you want to store in 'freq'. Assuming MAX_CHARS is 26, you actually want to store `str[i] - 'A'` or `str[i] - 'a'` depending on whether `str[i]` is an upper or lower-case character, and then you'll need to add back 'A' or 'a' to max in the printf line. (If it's actually 256 then storing just str[i] is fine.)

Comment: Instead you probably want to test vowel-or-not in the 'Finds maximum frequency' loop, and have separate 'max_vowel' and 'max_consonant'.

Comment: @Rup I understand you, I will make some adjustments , but I want the program to read the entire text and then define the most frequent vowel in the text
What I could do is the program reads the entire text and selects only the duplicate
I could not write a code identifying the most frequent vowel and this is what I needed

Comment: nikolajole `Initializes frequency of all characters to 0` is amiss - not quite "all".  `for(i=0; i<MAX_CHARS; i++)` likely initializes 127 elements.  Typically there are 256 different  `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Since I was explicitly asked in the comments, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct max {
        int count;
        int value;
};
/* CAUTION: this incorrectly reports that '\0' is a vowel.
   exercise for the reader. */
int isvowel(int c) 
{ 
        return strchr("aeiou", tolower(c)) != NULL;
}
int isconsonant(int c) 
{ 
        return isalpha(c) && ! isvowel(c);
}

int main(void)
{
        int c;
        struct max consonant = {0}, vowel = {0};
        int count[256] = {0};
        while( ( c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF ) {
                assert( c < 256 );
                count[c] += 1;
                if( isvowel(c) && count[c] > vowel.count ) {
                        vowel.count = count[c];
                        vowel.value = c;
                } else if( isconsonant(c) && count[c] > consonant.count ) {
                        consonant.count = count[c];
                        consonant.value = c;
                }
        }
        printf("%c appears %d time%s, %c appears %d time%s\n",
                vowel.value, vowel.count, vowel.count > 1 ? "s" : "",
                consonant.value, consonant.count, consonant.count > 1 ? "s" : "" );
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This expects ctrl-Z (or ctrl-D on Windows) to end the input if you're typing into a console. Or it will work with a file piped in on the command line rather than input

Comment: No, it doesn't take input "to infinity".  It reads the input stream until the input stream is closed.

Comment: Note: `isvowel('\0')` is true.  Might want to recode that.  Not that _null chracter_ input is common, yet possible.

Comment: @chux, yes, I noted that in a comment.  It's easy to fix, and I thought I would leave it as an exercise for the reader. (Which is to say I didn't notice it originally, then decided to punt on adding the easy fix.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ah yes, now is see the comment.  For me, code speaks louder than comments.  No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short solution I had fun assembling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_most_frequent(int count[], const char const* set, char* letter, int *number)
{
    *letter = '\0';
    *number = 0;
    for(int i=0; set[i]; ++i)
    {
        *letter = (count[set[i]-'a'] > *number)? set[i]            : *letter;
        *number = (count[set[i]-'a'] > *number)? count[set[i]-'a'] : *number;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    const char str[] = "My sample text, that Contains many vowels And consanants of all shapes and sizes; along with UPPER and LOWER cases.";
    const char vowels[] = "aeiou";
    const char cnsts[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    int max;
    char letter;
    int count[26] = {};

    for(int i=0; str[i]; ++i)
    {
        count[tolower(str[i])-'a'] += !!isalpha(str[i]);
    }

    // Most frequent vowel
    get_most_frequent(count, vowels, &letter, &max);
    printf("Vowel %c appears %d times\n", letter, max);

    // Most frequent consonant
    get_most_frequent(count, cnsts, &letter, &max);
    printf("Consonant %c appears %d times\n", letter, max);

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4532KB
Vowel a appears 13 times
Consonant s appears 11 times
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I mean
Here the program read the letter (a) is the most frequent, is it possible to appear the (a) letter most frequently in output
Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Interesting  dissimilar use of `str[i]` and `i<strlen(set)` to stop a `for()`.  With `i<strlen(set)`, I'd expect O(n*n) performance with the function as compiler cannot assume`strlen(set)` is constant given  `*letter = ...`

Comment: If it really matters to you, @chux... you seem to spend *a lot* of time reviewing and commenting on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already figured out the most frequent vowel/ consonant, you might pass it to a switch case like this:

```
switch(c)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
                    printf("\nThe most frequent vowel is: %c", c);
                    break;
        default:
                    printf("\nThe most frequent consonant is: %c", c);
    }
```

In case if you just want to know whether the most repeated character is a vowel/ consonant, the switch case could do the job. I haven't cheked your entire code, but if here:

```
printf("Maximum occurring character is '%c' = %d times.", max, freq[max]);
```

`max` contains the most frequent character in your string, you could simply pass `max` to the switch case and print the output from the switch case itself.

Comment: I think requirement is both the most frequent vowel and the most frequent consonant, not just one of them.

Comment: The questioner has already commented this:
@Josiah I created the entire program, but it works according to the most repeated character without specifying whether it is vowel or consonants

So, I thought the method of finding the most frequent character is already found out

Comment: @zeroSpook I cannot combine the code you sent with my code. Do you add it, please